# MySQL syntax error when joining tables based on user input

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have five tables that produce the results I need, but with five different queries.

Tables are [temperature, partSize, volume, stiffness and weight].  Each table has a column "type" that holds identical values among all tables.

The following queries gives me the results I need...but in five different tables.

```
$result_temp = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM temperature WHERE '%{$_POST['temperature']}%' LIKE '%{$_SESSION['temperature']}%'");

$result_size = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM partSize WHERE '%{$_POST['partSize']}%' LIKE '%{$_SESSION['partSize']}%'");

$result_vol = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM volume WHERE '%{$_POST['volume']}%' LIKE '%{$_SESSION['volume']}%'");

$result_stiff = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM stiffness WHERE '%{$_POST['stiffness']}%' LIKE '%{$_SESSION['stiffness']}%'");

$result_wght = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM weight WHERE '%{$_POST['weight']}%' LIKE '%{$_SESSION['weight']}%'");
```

I need a solution that combines the results of these tables and I am stuck.  I keep getting this error:  `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean`

I'm know mySQL will do this and I'm pretty sure it's a simple syntax error but I cannot figure this out.

I've tried this (and many variations...with CONCAT, without CONCAT, tick marks, no tick marks):

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `temperature` WHERE CONCAT ('%{$_POST['partSize']}%') LIKE CONCAT ('%{$_SESSION['partSize']}%') INNER JOIN `partSize` ON temperature.type = partSize.type INNER JOIN `volume` ON partSize.type = volume.type INNER JOIN `stiffness` ON volume.type = stiffness.type INNER JOIN `weight` ON stiffness.type = weight.type ");
```

The problem seems to arise as soon as I try to INNER JOIN or JOIN the tables. I've spent hours on this already.  :/  Can anyone help?

Comment: Your syntax is not correct.  `INNER JOIN` is an operator used in the `FROM` clause.  `WHERE` is a separate clause that follows the `FROM` clause.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: You have your query in the wrong order. The format should be `SELECT [columns] FROM [table] INNER JOIN [other table] WHERE [conditions]`. You have your `joins` coming after the `where` part which is invalid..

Comment: `WHERE '%{$_POST['temperature']}%' LIKE '%{$_SESSION['temperature']}%'` makes little sense. It's not testing anything from the database table. It will either return all rows or no rows, depending on whether the test is true or false.

Comment: Also, wildcards should just be in the second parameter to `LIKE`. The first parameter is the string you're testing against the pattern.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `LIKE` so much? If the user enters temperature `5`, you'll match `15`, `52`, `105`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what version of PHP you're using, but I'd encourage you to switch to PDO and to also use prepared statements (regardless of your version). However the syntax for your statement should be:

```
SELECT [columns] FROM [first table] INNER JOIN [other tables] ON [first table] WHERE [conditions]
```

With that being said, take a look at this example:

```
<?php
$config =  array(
  'host' => '[db host ip]',
  'username' => '[db username]',
  'password' => '[db password]',
  'name' => '[db name]'
);

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=$config[name];host=$config[host];charset=utf8mb4";
$db = new PDO($dsn, $config['username'], $config['password']);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$stmt = $db->prepare('
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `temperature` AS t
  INNER JOIN `partSize`  AS p ON t.`type` = p.`type`
  INNER JOIN `volumne`   AS v ON t.`type` = v.`type`
  INNER JOIN `stiffness` AS s ON t.`type` = s.`type`
  INNER JOIN `weight`    AS w ON t.`type` = w.`type`
WHERE
  t.`temperature` LIKE CONCAT('%', :temperature, '%') AND
  t.`partSize`    LIKE CONCAT('%', :partSize, '%')    AND
  t.`volumne`     LIKE CONCAT('%', :volumne, '%')     AND
  t.`stiffness`   LIKE CONCAT('%', :stiffness, '%')   AND
  t.`weight`      LIKE CONCAT('%', :weight, '%');');

// Execute the query passing the $_POST values as the parameters
$stmt->execute(array(
  ':temperature' => $_POST['temperature'],
  ':partSize'    => $_POST['partSize'],
  ':volume'      => $_POST['volume'],
  ':stiffness'   => $_POST['stiffness'],
  ':weight'      => $_POST['weight']
);

// Get all of the rows returned by the query and store them in an associative array
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```